Searching a list in F# with multiple fields
I have a mixed list in F# that looks like the following:
let list1 = [("a1",[1;2;3;8]);("a2",[2;8;6;10]);("s3",[4;8;5;12])]

Is there a way to retrieve [1;2;3;8] if pass the string "a1"?

There are many ways to do this. In most situations, I would do
let list1 = [("a1", [1; 2; 3; 8]); ("a2", [2; 8; 6; 10]); ("s3", [4; 8; 5; 12])]
let map1 = Map list1
let elem = map1["a1"]
printfn $"{elem}"

Or, if you are not sure "a1" is in the list:
match map1.TryFind "a1" with
| Some a -> printfn $"{a}"
| None -> printfn "key not found"

Other options are
let elem2 = list1 |> List.find (fun (key, _) -> key = "a1") |> snd
let elem3 = list1 |> List.pick (fun (key, value) -> if key = "a1" then Some value else None)

Or, again, to avoid exceptions for missing items (and, for a change, using function)
let elem4 = list1 |> List.tryPick (function "a1", x -> Some x | _ -> None)


Very elegant! However, map introduces a comparison constraint, while dict would only need equality.

You can implement your own tryLookup function for that:
let tryLookup key xs = 
  xs |> List.tryFind (fst >> (=) key) |> Option.map snd

Then:
let list1 = [("a1",[1;2;3;8]);("a2",[2;8;6;10]);("s3",[4;8;5;12])]
list1 |> tryLookup "a1" |> printfn "%A"
// => Some [1; 2; 3; 8]


As others have pointed out, there are many ways to do this. However, speaking from a traditional, functional background, this is a specialized fold.
let tryFind searchTerm = 
    List.fold ( fun accumulator element -> 
        match accumulator with 
        | Some a -> Some a 
        | None -> 
            if fst element = searchTerm
            then Some (snd element)
            else None
    ) None

let find searchTerm = 
    List.fold ( fun accumulator element -> 
        if fst element = searchTerm
        then snd element
        else state
    ) []

//for when you want an option
tryFind "a1" list1
|> printfn "%A"

//for when you *know* the item exists in the structure
find "a1" list1
|> printfn "%A"

We traverse the structure and make a reduction to a single element: fold.
